# What is the time complexity of Array.enumerated() in swift?

Tags: swift, algorithm, runtime

I used enumerated() quite often in my code like:

```
for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

If enumerated() takes O(n) time then the above execution will take O(2n).

I am confused here since Apple's documentation doesn't provide any info of time complexity.

Will this cause O(2n) or just O(n)?

Comment: Why would the `for` loop take O(2n) if it only does a single pass through the array?

Comment: Doesn't swift need to compute the result of enumerated() first?

Comment: O(2n) = O(n) for complexities. If you are worried about performance, benchmark

Comment: Right, but for very large arrays, is O(n) better than O(2n)? Or it appears the same?

Answer (score 1):

To be short its `O(1)`.

It's very well documented. You can get that info even in Xcode directly.
[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Swift is open source now and you can get this info from public sources.

From the [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d4c22ee2fa25d5323478892911f9dfc60d756838/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift).

Method description.

```
/// Returns a sequence of pairs (*n*, *x*), where *n* represents a
  /// consecutive integer starting at zero and *x* represents an element of
  /// the sequence.
  ///
  /// This example enumerates the characters of the string "Swift" and prints
  /// each character along with its place in the string.
  ///
  ///     for (n, c) in "Swift".enumerated() {
  ///         print("\(n): '\(c)'")
  ///     }
  ///     // Prints "0: 'S'"
  ///     // Prints "1: 'w'"
  ///     // Prints "2: 'i'"
  ///     // Prints "3: 'f'"
  ///     // Prints "4: 't'"
  ///
  /// When you enumerate a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter
  /// for the enumeration, but is not necessarily the index of the paired value.
  /// These counters can be used as indices only in instances of zero-based,
  /// integer-indexed collections, such as `Array` and `ContiguousArray`. For
  /// other collections the counters may be out of range or of the wrong type
  /// to use as an index. To iterate over the elements of a collection with its
  /// indices, use the `zip(_:_:)` function.
  ///
  /// This example iterates over the indices and elements of a set, building a
  /// list consisting of indices of names with five or fewer letters.
  ///
  ///     let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
  ///     var shorterIndices: [SetIndex<String>] = []
  ///     for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
  ///         if name.count <= 5 {
  ///             shorterIndices.append(i)
  ///         }
  ///     }
  ///
  /// Now that the `shorterIndices` array holds the indices of the shorter
  /// names in the `names` set, you can use those indices to access elements in
  /// the set.
  ///
  ///     for i in shorterIndices {
  ///         print(names[i])
  ///     }
  ///     // Prints "Sofia"
  ///     // Prints "Mateo"
  ///
  /// - Returns: A sequence of pairs enumerating the sequence.
```

Comment: so the runtime of enumerated() is the same as zip(indexes, elements)? which is O(n)?

Comment: The actual implementation is here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c35d508600516b892732e2fd3f0f0a17ca4562ba/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L116

Comment: Thx Alex! Thats awesome!